# ts cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser';

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

**Images of files**

[image: **app.module.ts file**]

[image: **app.component file**]

I am having this error and i am not able to figure that out.I am trying to import **angular/core** and **angular/platform-browser** . I followed many links on **stackoverflow** but none of them helped me out.

this is my **package.json file**

```
{   "name": "angular-2",   "version": "1.0.0",   "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"   },   "license": "ISC",   "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6"
       },   "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings":"^0.7.11"   } }
```

Comment: I think for verify your imports will be good if you can share your package.json

Comment: @Ricardo i have added package.json file

Comment: update your package.json file from this link https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json

Comment: after updating it is showing me the same error

Answer (score 16):

I think you need install and add @angular/platform-browser in your package.json you can do this:

```
npm install @angular/platform-browser --save
```

So, at this moment angular2 has a final version, youi don't need to use a beta version. You tagged your project like an ionic2 project, but he doesn't seen like a 
normal ionic2 app, you don't have any ionic/cordova dependecy in your package.json

Comment: Ricardo, I agree. 
You need to install everything that's missing:
sudo npm i @angular/core@<version>
sudo npm i @angular/compiler@<version>
sudo npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@<version>
 ...

Comment: this fixed this issue for me, aim at the directory your project is installed in and run the above. thanks for this!

Answer (score 9):

Gone through same problem, and here's one firm solution to this.

I am assuming you have generated an angular cli project and this is what you have ran into once you've started to code.

### Solution

So what happens is at times angular fails to install all the required dependencies, and does not even update on npm install.

Steps

```
1. Delete existing folders @angular & @angular-devkit inside node_modules folder
2. perform npm install, or yarn
```

And this should work for almost all scenarios. At Least worked for me couple of times.

Answer (score 7):

Try running

> npm install -g @angular/cli

if still getting errors then close and reopen your editor I faced it in my Visual Studio when I copied src of my existing project and placed it in newly created cli project (to avoid making new components again)

Comment: close and reopen your editor!!!!!!!!!!
i spend hours before i find this answer.

Comment: Spent hours trying to find a solution then booooom!!!! your answer saved the day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the `dependencies` were just not `installed` right, or maybe you need to `re-install` them. I had a similar issue and all these answers are good.

**try in your terminal:**

```
npm install --save @angular/platform-browser

npm install --save @angular/core
```

hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue, delete the node modules folder and then clean the cache using >npm cache clean --force.
Install the node modules again globally using
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

it will work

Comment: Hii Aparna. Thanks for you answer! Just a suggestion: stackoverflow supports code blocks. You can use them to make your answer clearer, with the commands you mentioned inside the code blocks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your package.json, you are using older version of angular2

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13"
```

You need to use below dependecies in your package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
```

Please note - From angular2 2.0.0-rc.0 version, they moved into scoped packages hence you will see `@angular/<packagename>`. Before this, it was angular2. Refer this [info](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02)

For latest versions refer this [link](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

Comment: i have updated my dependency but still the error is same

Comment: After updating dependency, have you ran `npm install` command?

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer by applying changes to the **tsconfig file**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and I also updated **package.json file**.

Comment: What changes to tsconfig file? Which setting was the problem, or which ones did you add?

Also, what did you update in your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall @types/node:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/node
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

If it doesn't help try the same with typescript:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev typescript
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your application and its dependencies by using ng update command, like this:

```
ng update --all=true --force
```

here, flag all is set to true to update all dependencies and flag force is used to do it forcefully as name suggests.Now after doing so you may face some vulnerabilities for few dependencies which can be fixed by manually installing those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the commands below in the terminal.

**The Commands:**

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/forms --save
sudo npm install -g @angular/core --save 
sudo npm install -g @angular/platform-browser --save
```

`sudo` for giving the root access to the current angular project folder and `-g` for installing it globally.

Answer (score -5):

Just use bellow command at project path.

```
E:\Ratna\Angular\Project1\Demo>npm install

npm install
```

it is works.

Comment: This is entirely off topic